# $ \|T\|=\sup _{\|x\|=\|y\|=1}|\langle T x, y\rangle|$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

> If $T : H \to H$ is a bounded linear operator on hilbert space $H$ then:
> $
> \|T\|=\sup _{\|x\|=\|y\|=1}|\langle T x, y\rangle|$
> and with example show that $\|T\|=\sup _{\|x\|=1}|\langle  Tx,y\rangle|$ is not true .

For showing
$$\|\ T \|\ = \sup_{\|\ x \|\ = 1 = \|\ y \|\ } | \langle y , T(x) \rangle | $$
again first by Cauchy-Schwarz
$$\sup_{\|\ x \|\ = 1 = \|\ y \|\ } | \langle y , T(x) \rangle | \leq \sup_{\|\ x \|\ = 1 = \|\ y \|\ }  \|\ y \|\ \|\ Tx \|\ \leq \sup_{\|\ x \|\ = 1 = \|\ y \|\ }  \|\ y \|\ \|\ T \|\  \|\ x \|\ = \|\ T \|\ $$
For the reverse inequality ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\|x\|=1$ and suppose $Tx\ne0$. Let $y=\|Tx\|^{-1}Tx$. Then $\|y\|=1$ and
$$\left<Tx,y\right>=\|Tx\|^{-1}\left<Tx,Tx\right>=\|Tx\|.$$
So
$$\sup_{\|x\|=\|y\|=1}|\left<Tx,y\right>|\ge\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|.$$

Answer (score 1):

Take $y=\frac {Tx}{\|Tx\|}$. We get $\sup \langle Tx, y \rangle \geq \sup_x \frac  1 {\|Tx\|} \langle Tx, Tx \rangle =\sup_x\|Tx\|=\|T\|$.

There is a typo in the second part. $y$ should be replaced by $x$. For a counter-example take rotation by $90$ degrees in $\mathbb R^{2}$

Comment: why  rotation by $90$ degrees in $\mathbb R^{2}$ is counter-example ?

Comment: @amirbahadory For rotation by $90$ degrees $ \langle Tx, x \rangle=0$ for all $x$ so the supremum is also $0$. But $\|T\|\neq 0$/

Comment: why $||T|| $ is not $0$ ?

Comment: Is $T$ the zero operator? An operator has norm $0$ iff it is the zero operator. (What is $T((1,0)$?) @amirbahadory